# Rails: NameError: uninitialized constant Article::ImageUploader when using Carrierwave on rails 4.1.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I'm learning rails 4.1.5

I got this error:

```
2.1.1 :008 > Article
NameError: uninitialized constant Article::ImageUploader
    from /Volumes/disk0s4/www/rails/blog/app/models/article.rb:4:in `<class:Article>'
    from /Volumes/disk0s4/www/rails/blog/app/models/article.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from (irb):8
    from /Users/didin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/didin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/didin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /Users/didin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/didin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Volumes/disk0s4/www/rails/blog/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/didin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/didin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

my file: article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base    
    validates_presence_of :title, :body
    belongs_to :user
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

I got error when running `rails console`

when I write a word '**Article**' on the console, it raises error above, but it working fine when this line `mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader` at article.rb's file removed.

when that line is restored, the error comes again. so it seems the error is caused that line, but I'm not sure.

anyone can fix this, please...

thank you for reading and answer :-)

Answer (score 71):

I know this is a few months late but I stumbled across this issue myself. My solution was to paste

> require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'

into the config/environment.rb file. Just append it at the end.

My Env:
Ruby 2.1.2p95 ;
Rails 4.1.7 ; 
Carrierwave-0.10.0

Comment: Thanks, I skipped over this while following the guide.

Answer (score 31):

I added this to `application.rb`

```
require 'carrierwave'
require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
```

Rails 4.2.0, Ruby 2.2.2, Carrierwave 0.10.0

Comment: I'd like to point out in the CarrierWave docs it says: "Make sure you are loading CarrierWave after loading your ORM, otherwise you'll need to require the relevant extension manually"

Comment: First line is most likely not needed. It gets executed as part of `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)` line.

Answer (score 27):

Ill put it here, just in case..

IF you are using `spring` gem then you have to "restart" it by changing `config/application.rb` or close and open terminal, or: `$ bin/spring stop`

You can inspect its processes lifetime here(scroll to right):

```
$ ps aux | grep spring
alexey           55936   0.0  0.9  2645908  78440   ??  Ss   Thu06PM   0:13.17 spring app    | myapp | started 26 hours ago | development mode
alexey           81963   0.0  0.0  2481764   1608   ??  S    Sat11PM   0:01.91 spring server | myapp | started 141 hours ago
```

And kill it if needed.

More info at: https://github.com/rails/spring

Comment: Adding spaces to config/application.rb and saving worked for me!

Comment: Worth noting, I tried restarting the server, and guard, but modifying the `application.rb` file did it for me (whitespace). I never tried restarting terminal, but now I'n guessing that also would have done it.

Comment: Just stopping spring gem using `bin/spring stop` did it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Are you using spring?

I got two terminal windows, one for server, the other for console.

After I **restarted my server and enter console again**, the error disappeared.

And I didn't add any line in application.rb

Rails 4.2.4, Ruby 2.3.0, Carrierwave 0.10.0 a2c93fe

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you're using CarrierWave gem for file uploads. Have you checked that it was properly installed?
You could issue the command to check:

```
bundle show carrierwave
```

In my case, I've bundle installed on a different terminal where I ran rails console. HTH!

Comment: Exactly. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Another tip try: Open up the uploaded that was just generated.  Ensure the name of the uploader class matches the name of the class you added in your model.

Answer (score 2):

If error appears in rails app' specs only you may be missing

```
require 'rails_helper'
```

at the top :)

Answer (score 1):

Exit and start your console again.
In this case just reload! won't solve.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error and then it worked after restarting the server.

This occurs rather frequently.  In development, the error crops up.  The uploader was probably just added. Removing spring resolves, but that is a band-aid.  The simple server re-start is often the proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I forgot to run `rails g uploader image`. Once done, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this
in appliccation.rb correct module name
this fix same problem for me

```
module CorrectName #OldName  <---------------
     # Do not swallow errors in after_commit/after_rollback callbacks.
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I uninstalled both the below gems

```
gem 'spring'
gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case in my 'user.rb' module file, I had added the following lines:

```
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
  mount_uploader :coverimage, CoverimageUploader
```

I had to quit them and

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has a preloader, such as Spring in place, before uninstalling the otherwise useful preloaded that speeds up your app, it's worth stopping it so that load paths will be reinitialised and any uploader in `app/uploaders` will be loaded once a new console or a rails process start. Try `bin/spring stop`. It will restart once it's necessary, now with the uploaders in place.