# Paperclip giving NameError: uninitialized constant Model::ImageUploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, paperclip

I Have found a similar question:
[NameError: uninitialized constant Article::ImageUploader when using Carrierwave on rails 4.1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25712027/nameerror-uninitialized-constant-articleimageuploader-when-using-carrierwave)

But I have tried the suggestions there:
carrierwave is installed and bundle is complete
And I have double checked my models.

My user model has:

```
has_one :image, :as => :assetable, :class_name => "User::Image", :dependent => :destroy
```

And my user creation works find but as soon as I try to access the views it breaks by this code:

```
 <%= link_to image_tag((current_user.image.nil? ? Settings.default_user_image : current_user.image.attachment.url(:thumbnail)) , :style=>'max-width:60px;', :alt=>current_user.full_name, :title=>current_user.full_name), user_path(current_user) %>
```

I am not sure why this broke, earlier it was working fine, only thing I can think of is, I did bundle once again when my gemfile.lock got conflicts.

This is how I replicate the issue on rails console:

```
2.1.1 :001 > u = User.new
2.1.1 :002 > u.build_image
NameError: uninitialized constant User::User::Image
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:133:in `compute_type'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:190:in `klass'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:207:in `build_association'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:247:in `build_record'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/associations/singular_association.rb:29:in `build'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/associations/builder/singular_association.rb:18:in `build_image'
        from (irb):2
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Please help. I am stuck at a critical point right now.

Path to the file where error is happening is:
/demo/app/views/home/index.html.erb

Image class resides in:
/demo/app/models/user/image.rb

Contents for image.rb

```
class User::Image < Asset
  has_attached_file :attachment, {
    fog_credentials: {:aws_access_key_id=>"***", :aws_secret_access_key=>"***", :provider=>"AWS"}, :fog_public=>true, :fog_directory=>"test",

    styles: { :thumbnail => "60x60#", :profile => "165x165#" },
    storage: :multiple,
    path: ":compatible_rails_root/users/files/:id/:style.:extension",
    url:  "/uploads/posts/files/:id/:style.:extension",
    multiple_if:     lambda { |user| true },
    display_from_s3: lambda { |user| true }
  }

  validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
end
```

User mode is simply in
/demo/app/models

Comment: Can you post the paths to image and user classes?

Comment: @neo  updated the question, with the requested information..

Comment: After digging into ActiveRecord code, I suppose there is some `NameError` when rails try to import `User::Image`. Try to use `has_one :image, :class_name => "::User::Image"` (!note leading `::` in class_name), it can give you better stacktrace. Add that stacktrace to question then.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your namespaces are wrong, try to write your classes as follows (note the introduced `Users` module):

```
# app/models/users/image.rb
module Users
  class Image < Asset
    has_attached_file :attachment, { # ... 
    # ....
  end
end
```

and just modify a line referring to the `Image` class in `User` class (the only change is that it's `Users::Image` now:

```
# app/models/users.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :image, :as => :assetable, :class_name => "Users::Image", #...
  # ...
end
```

this (and maybe one restart of the server later) and everything should be fine.